# Understanding methods syntax in Objective-C and Objective-J

Tags: objective-c, cappuccino, objective-j

I've a simple question about objective-c / objective-j syntax.

This is a method dataForItemsAtIndexes and it gets as parameters a CPIndextSet and CPString.
It should return a CPData object. However I don't understand what's **(CPCollectionView)aCollectionView**.

```
- (CPData)collectionView:(CPCollectionView)aCollectionView
   dataForItemsAtIndexes:(CPIndexSet)indices
                 forType:(CPString)aType
```

Thanks

Comment: Nice to see somebody using Cappuccino :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That identifies the `CPCollectionView` which your implementing data source corresponds to. This is useful in case your view or window has multiple `CPCollectionView`s, whose data sources are the same object, so it knows which view to provide which data to.

Comment: @BoltClock uhm, so are CPData and CPCollectionView both returned by the method ? Is CPCollectionView children of CPData ? If yes, why do they specify CPData ?

Comment: @Patrick: Nope, the method only returns a `CPData`. The `CPCollectionView` is passed in as an argument so you can obtain information about it within your delegate method. So in essence there are really *three* parameters: the collection view, the index set and the type string.

Comment: @BoltClock All right, now it makes sense. However I'm a bit confused with the methods signature. Can parameters be specified before the method names ? (If so, why ?) Here aCollectionView is placed before the method name dataForItemsAtIndexes, right ?

Comment: @Patrick: The method name is actually made up of all the parameter names. In this case, the method is called `collectionView:dataForItemsAtIndexes:forType:` (notice the colons to represent the three parameters). The word that immediately follows the return type is the start of the method name.

Comment: @BoltClock wow, so there is not method name ? I thought you need a method name, at least this is what I've read on wikipedia: -(return_type)method_name:(param1_type)param1_varName

Comment: @BoltClockWhat happens if you need 2 methods with the same arguments, if you don't specify method names ? thanks

Comment: @Patrick: No, like I said the entire thing is the method name. Here, `method_name:(param1_type)param1_varName` is `collectionView:(CPCollectionView *)aCollectionView`.

Comment: @Patrick: to have two methods with the same parameter types just name the left sides of each parameter expression differently.